# How to fix aloha/twilio warning

Tags: php, laravel-5, twilio

In my Laravel 5.7 app ( PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, dev mode) I
Installed https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio plugin

```
  - Installing twilio/sdk (5.23.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing aloha/twilio (4.0.2): Downloading (100%)
```

and using it I got error:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_URL - assumed 'CURLOPT_URL' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

and no sms was sent. I suppose that I can to switch off E_WARNING at my local server, but as my app is still under development
mode I would like to keep it.

Which can be decision here ?

MODIFIED:

I have :

$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
...

Also My phpinfo shows installed and enabled:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4mw5.jpg

In my package manager I see :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOBE6.jpg

Is something not installed or activated at my server ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the CURL extension is either not installed or enabled. To see if its enabled you can run `php -m` from your CLI and check under `[PHP Modules]`.

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED block with my configuration.

Comment: It seems you may have a bug, try reinstalling the module to make sure: `sudo apt purge php-curl php7.2-curl && sudo apt install php7.2-curl`